# Maps fragment in tabbed activity is not showing the markers?

Tags: android, maps, tabactivity

Using generic tabbed activity from the android studio and google maps. Map appears but without the markers. I have no idea how to fix this, hope it's understandable.
Referencing the tab:

```
else if (getArguments().getInt(ARG_SECTION_NUMBER)==2){
            View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_sub_page2, container, false);

            return rootView;
        }
```

Fragment tab

```
public class SubPage2 extends Fragment implements OnMapReadyCallback {
public GoogleMap mMap;
@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, 
Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_sub_page2, container,false);
}

@Override
public void onViewCreated(View view, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);

    android.app.FragmentManager fragment = getActivity().getFragmentManager();
    final MapFragment myMapFragment = (MapFragment) fragment.findFragmentById(R.id.map);
    myMapFragment.getMapAsync(this);

}

@Override
public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
 mMap=googleMap;
      LatLng marker = new LatLng(-33.867, 151.206);

   mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(marker, 13));

    mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().title("Hello Google Maps!").position(marker));
}
```

Subpage 2 layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 android:layout_width="match_parent"
 android:layout_height="match_parent"
 xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

 <fragment android:id="@+id/map"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
class="com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment"

>

</fragment>

 </FrameLayout>
```

In case anyone else has the same problem the solution is adding a few lines in the calling statement - >

```
   else if (getArguments().getInt(ARG_SECTION_NUMBER)==2){
            View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_sub_page2, container, false);
            FragmentManager manager = getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager();
            FragmentTransaction transaction = manager.beginTransaction();
            transaction.replace(R.id.map, new SubPage2()).commit();
            return rootView;
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code looks okay. Just a hunch, have you checked to make sure you've tried a range of zoom levels to determine whether the text might be too tiny to see?

You can enable the zoom controls using `mMap.getUiSettings().setZoomControlsEnabled(true);`.

There's a possibility that the `Title` might only control the text that's displayed for that marker once it has gained focus, i.e. been clicked on. To eliminate any chance of uploading an empty marker, could you try supplying a `BitmapDescriptor` too?

**BitmapDescriptor Example**

```
// Allocate the MarkerBitmap.
final BitmapDescriptor lMarkerBitmap = BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.my_marker_image);
// Add the Marker.
mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().alpha(1.0f)
                                  .position(marker)
                                  .title("Hello Google Maps!")
                                  .icon(lMarkerBitmap));
```

Comment: Just tried it, no improvement. I think onMapReady is not even executed.

Comment: I've just tried your code on my map and it seems to work okay (without a `BitmapDescriptor`!). Do you receive any `Exception`s? Can you see the map geography at all?

Comment: No exceptions at all and yes the map itself appears and I can scroll through it. I'm sure the api key I'm using is right too.

Comment: I added the layout too if that could be useful.

Comment: Using `android:layout_width="wrap_content"` looks a little strange, but if you can still see the `GoogleMap` that's probably not the problem.

Comment: Yeah, changed it to match_parent just in case, no luck. Can you share your code here? https://codeshare.io/